Error when we wanted to delete the agent after the flow
we have created a model which has more the 50,000 data flowing, but we released that anylogic has a limitation of 50,000 agents created. so we have decided to delete the agent once the flow is completed. But we are facing the error - "Error in deleteSelf(), agent should belong to some population"
Can you suggest some solution so we can created more agents then 50k and flow the model.
we have tried multiple options to delete the agents after the flow is completed (at sink) and unable to do it.
we are expected to give us a solution so we can created more agents then 50k and complete our model (deletion after the flow is good no need to store anything)


Can you suggest some solution so we can create more agents then 50k and flow the model.

You can't with the Personal Learning Edition, this is a limitation in the software, see the documentation: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/editions.html#limitations
As Benjamin's comment said, the agents are already deleted in the Sink, but you cannot create more than 50k agents in one simulation run in the free version regardless of how many are currently in the system.

thx for clarifying that the limit is the total number ever created


we have tried multiple options to delete the agents after the flow is completed (at sink) and unable to do it.

The Sink is deleting the agents for you, no further code or action needed. Simply let your agents end their life via a Sink and your total agent count will reduce accordingly.

thanks for the response
can you please tell us what exactly the 50k mark is?
we have a database of more then 50k in excel, we are trying to create a model in which agents will flow through it row by row, but it says the max limit of agents which created dynamically is 50k.
can you give us a solutions how to flow the data with more then50k?

There is no solution but to get the full version or create fewer agents. As per @mczandrea the total number of agents ever created is what counts (not the "live" number that currently exists). There is no "hack" or secret trick.
